# php funtion calling inside a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying to make a page with several buttons(or links) that will direct to different pages.

I have tried this by using the following code that should redirect the user to google.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form id='form' action="main.php">

    <button id="allSetsButton" class="float-left submit-button"> main</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("allSetsButton").onclick = function (){
location.href = 'http://google.com';
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I press the button, the page refreshes instead of redirecting me.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `</scipt>` shoul say script

Comment: Ok so you call a PHP page located at `main.php` , now debug the received values with `var_dump($_GET);` and stuff

Comment: how would i do that? i know how to debug on java but not on php.

Comment: I gave you the exact code, just paste that line just under the php-tag

Comment: Remove the form tag ... Form is only supposed to be kept when you need to submit some value. If you want to redirect to a link then simply use the link tag <a href="">... Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to your button element so that it's not considered as a submit button for the form (which causes to submit the form before your event handler can do anything).

```
<button type="button" id="allSetsButton" class="float-left submit-button"> main</button>
```

Comment: market this one as solved because of the short explaining. the other 2 answers where correct too.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your requeriments, why don't you just use plain links and style them as you need?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style>
  .submit-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background-color: #e1ecf4;
  }
</style>
<body>
<form id='form' action="main.php">
  <a href="http://google.com" class="float-left submit-button">Main</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

U can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<form id='form' action="main.php">

<button type="button" id="allSetsButton" class="float-left submit-button" onClick="gotoweb()"> main</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function gotoweb(){
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
        };
</script>

</body>
```

or this in short

```
<button type="button" id="allSetsButton" class="float-left submit-button" onClick="window.location.href='http://google.com'">  main</button>
```